# How to override template for angular material 2 datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, overriding, angular-material, angular2-template

I need to modify the templates for the angular 2 material date-picker. Its templates are declared in several internal components that are defined in @angular/material/esm5/datepicker.es5.js.

I could modify the template directly in the node package, but then it would get overwritten when updating.

The only two ways I can see this being possible is if I modify the template dynamically (is this really possible?), or if I copy over the entire angular material node package locally and then modify that (what is the best way to do this?). Thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to create a new component that extends the component you want to create a new template for? If you do that you can reuse the code and get to make your own template.

Comment: I would, but the template is for a component that I'm not directly using. To give you more context, I'm using the MatDatepicker component. The MatDatepicker component uses the internal component MatCalendar, which has the template that I'm trying to modify.

Comment: So extend both of them. Use the same template text that the MatDatePicker is using with a change from using the MatCalendar to use MyMatCalendar

Comment: The issue with this is that MatDatepicker is referencing MatCalendar via private methods and properties.. So this is impossible. (Actually, I got the names of the classes wrong.. MatDatepicker uses MatDatepickerContent  via private methods and properties and MatDatepickerContent uses MatCalendar.

Comment: @br4yd3n we also had similar kind of requirement to achieve that we forked the existing git repo  and used our own custom directive

Comment: @br4yd3n could you please add more about how did you achieve it? Did you modified the template in MatCalendar and in MatDatepickerContent?

Answer (score 2):

you have two ways:

1. create a new component extending the material datepicker and assign you won template
2. override some material css rules in order to change its look and feel

Comment: I don't want to just change it's look and feel, I want to add content, so sounds like a custom template extended from mat-datepicker has to be the way to go.